# Python Popen Subprocess - interacting with executable not possible until stdin is closed

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, popen

I am trying to interact with a Commandline Executable, but I am stucked.
I would like to print out every line, the .exe is producing to stdout.
Until I get "condition" in a line -> then it should write "y\n" to stdin

This works, but as soon as I am writing to stdin, I don't get any stdout output anymore. I only get the output, if I close the stdin -> but afterwards I am not able to interact anymore, because the .exe stops.

Any hints?
Thanks!

```
    proc = Popen([test.exe], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)


    while True:
      line = proc.stdout.readline()
      print(line)
      if not line: break
      if "condition" in line.decode(): break
    
    proc.stdin.write('{}\n'.format("y\n").encode('utf-8'))
    proc.stdin.close()

    while True:
      line = proc.stdout.readline()
      print(line)
      if not line: break
      if "Group" in line.decode(): break
    
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: Programs often buffer output to pipes, which doesn't work well for interactive use. Use `pexpect` to control interactive applications

Answer (score 0):

consider flushing the program's `stdin` to avoid python buffering the pipe, instead of closing the pipe.

```py
proc.stdin.write('{}\n'.format("y\n").encode('utf-8'))
proc.stdin.flush()
```

also if only text is passed through the pipe then consider passing `Popen(....,text=True)` to avoid all the `encode` and `decode`.